# Failed to export android application (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, export

I updated my `Eclipse` to the new version, and now I can't export my signed applications. 
Below is the error report:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_26
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=hr_HR
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Wed Dec 14 15:58:02 CET 2011
Failed to export application

Command-line Error 2 
Output: 
ERROR: Unknown command 'crunch' 
Android Asset Packaging Tool 

Usage: 
 aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk} 
   List contents of Zip-compatible archive. 

 aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]] 
   badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK. 
   permissions      Print the permissions from the APK. 
   resources        Print the resource table from the APK. 
   configurations   Print the configurations in the APK. 
   xmltree          Print the compiled xmls in the given assets. 
   xmlstrings       Print the strings of the given compiled xml assets. 

 aapt p[ackage] [-d][-f][-m][-u][-v][-x][-z][-M AndroidManifest.xml] \ 
        [-0 extension [-0 extension ...]] [-g tolerance] [-j jarfile] \ 
        [--debug-mode] [--min-sdk-version VAL] [--target-sdk-version VAL] \ 
        [--app-version VAL] [--app-version-name TEXT] [--custom-package VAL] \ 
        [--rename-manifest-package PACKAGE] \ 
        [--rename-instrumentation-target-package PACKAGE] \ 
        [--utf16] [--auto-add-overlay] \ 
        [--max-res-version VAL] \ 
        [-I base-package [-I base-package ...]] \ 
        [-A asset-source-dir]  [-G class-list-file] [-P public-definitions-file] \ 
        [-S resource-sources [-S resource-sources ...]]         [-F apk-file] [-J R-file-dir] \ 
        [--product product1,product2,...] \ 
        [raw-files-dir [raw-files-dir] ...] 

   Package the android resources.  It will read assets and resources that are 
   supplied with the -M -A -S or raw-files-dir arguments.  The -J -P -F and -R 
   options control which files are output. 

 aapt r[emove] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...] 
   Delete specified files from Zip-compatible archive. 

 aapt a[dd] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...] 
   Add specified files to Zip-compatible archive. 

 aapt v[ersion] 
   Print program version. 

 Modifiers: 
   -a  print Android-specific data (resources, manifest) when listing 
   -c  specify which configurations to include.  The default is all 
       configurations.  The value of the parameter should be a comma 
       separated list of configuration values.  Locales should be specified 
       as either a language or language-region pair.  Some examples: 
            en 
            port,en 
            port,land,en_US 
       If you put the special locale, zz_ZZ on the list, it will perform 
       pseudolocalization on the default locale, modifying all of the 
       strings so you can look for strings that missed the 
       internationalization process.  For example: 
            port,land,zz_ZZ 
   -d  one or more device assets to include, separated by commas 
   -f  force overwrite of existing files 
   -g  specify a pixel tolerance to force images to grayscale, default 0 
   -j  specify a jar or zip file containing classes to include 
   -k  junk path of file(s) added 
   -m  make package directories under location specified by -J 
   -u  update existing packages (add new, replace older, remove deleted files) 
   -v  verbose output 
   -x  create extending (non-application) resource IDs 
   -z  require localization of resource attributes marked with 
       localization="suggested" 
   -A  additional directory in which to find raw asset files 
   -G  A file to output proguard options into. 
   -F  specify the apk file to output 
   -I  add an existing package to base include set 
   -J  specify where to output R.java resource constant definitions 
   -M  specify full path to AndroidManifest.xml to include in zip 
   -P  specify where to output public resource definitions 
   -S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will be scanned 
       and the first match found (left to right) will take precedence. 
   -0  specifies an additional extension for which such files will not 
       be stored compressed in the .apk.  An empty string means to not 
       compress any files at all. 
   --debug-mode 
       inserts android:debuggable="true" in to the application node of the 
       manifest, making the application debuggable even on production devices. 
   --min-sdk-version 
       inserts android:minSdkVersion in to manifest.  If the version is 7 or 
       higher, the default encoding for resources will be in UTF-8. 
   --target-sdk-version 
       inserts android:targetSdkVersion in to manifest. 
   --max-res-version 
       ignores versioned resource directories above the given value. 
   --values 
       when used with "dump resources" also includes resource values. 
   --version-code 
       inserts android:versionCode in to manifest. 
   --version-name 
       inserts android:versionName in to manifest. 
   --custom-package 
       generates R.java into a different package. 
   --auto-add-overlay 
       Automatically add resources that are only in overlays. 
   --rename-manifest-package 
       Rewrite the manifest so that its package name is the package name 
       given here.  Relative class names (for example .Foo) will be 
       changed to absolute names with the old package so that the code 
       does not need to change. 
   --rename-instrumentation-target-package 
       Rewrite the manifest so that all of its instrumentation 
       components target the given package.  Useful when used in 
       conjunction with --rename-manifest-package to fix tests against 
       a package that has been renamed. 
   --product 
       Specifies which variant to choose for strings that have 
       product variants 
   --utf16 
       changes default encoding for resources to UTF-16.  Only useful when API 
       level is set to 7 or higher where the default encoding is UTF-8. 
   --non-constant-id 
       Make the resources ID non constant. This is required to make an R java class 
       that does not contain the final value but is used to make reusable compiled 
       libraries that need to access resources.
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeAapt(BuildHelper.java:887)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.updateCrunchCache(BuildHelper.java:161)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:131)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:290)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:229)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Yesterday everything was fine, but today after the update it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Since a recent upgrade of eclipse and ADT, I get failed exports with a popup saying Dalvik error code 1 (or similar). I still haven't tracked the cause - it takes 4 or 5 attempts to get the export to work (closing project then eclipse, open eclipse then project then export. Can't seem to find a pattern.

Comment: I updatet components in AVD and SDK manager to, and problem is gone :)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that - not sure if my problem is the same as yours though.

Comment: Deleting `bin/` and `gen/` (and waiting for them to be re-created automatically) may help. At least it did for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error during the same time. With the current ADT everything is fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Update to `ADT 18.0.0`, this should work.

Comment: No, updating to ADT 18 only introduces the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11006305/576267

Answer (score 1):

Same Error "Failed to export android application" in Eclipse for me. No answer/comment did help.

Then I tried "Android Tools/Export Unsigned ..." what gives the same Error, but with more details!!

In my case it was a file in the assets (sub-)directory two times, one time with capital letter, one time without.

Deleting (or renaming) one solved the error for Unsigned / Signed Packages.

Comment: The Details-Error-Message was:

Failed to export application
Command-line Error 1 
Output: 
Path1/Filename: error: File is case-insensitive equivalent to: Path2/filename

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be generic cause, "PARTIAL ADT UPDATE". Update the below, "Android SDK Platform-Tool" to 8 Rev and "Android Asset Packaging Tool" from android SDK manager.